# Skip a line from text file in Fortran90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm writing in fortran (90). My program must read file1, do something with every line of it and write result to file2. But the problem - file1 has some unneeded information in first line.

How can I skip a line from input file using Fortran?

The code:

```
open (18, file='m3dv.dat')
open (19, file='m3dv2.dat')
do
  read(18,*) x
  tmp = sqrt(x**2 + 1)
  write(19, *) tmp
end do
```

First line is a combination of text and numbers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One possible solution [has already been presented to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5611699) which uses a "dummy variable", but I just wanted to add that you **don't even need a dummy variable**, just a blank read statement before entering the loop is enough:

```
open(18, file='m3dv.dat')
read(18,*)
do
    ...
```

The other answers are correct but this can improve conciseness and (thus) readability of your code.

Comment: @osgx Yes. If you want to skip 3 lines, write it three times.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: I do not see any dummy variable in the question's body. I see one variable called `x`, which is then entered into a formula in the next line, so how could it be a "dummy" variable?

Comment: Right, it was referring to that first answer at the time. I approved your suggested edit, thanks for the cleanup!

Answer (score 1):

Perform a read operation before the do loop that reads whatever is on the first line into a "dummy" variable.

```
program linereadtest
implicit none
character (LEN=75) ::firstline
integer :: temp,n
    !
    !
    !
open(18,file='linereadtest.txt')
read(18,*) firstline
do n=1,4
   read(18,'(i3)') temp
   write(*,*) temp
end do
stop
end program linereadtest
```

Datafile:

> This is a test of 1000 things that 10
>   of which do not exist
>
> ```
> 50
> 100
> 34
> 566
> ```

!ignore the space in between the line and the numbers, I can't get it to format

Comment: how can I read `whatever` in fortran? First line have several space-separated strings and numbers.

Comment: Make a character array (LEN=100, or whatever).  I believe `read` should read until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
open (18, file='m3dv.dat')
open (19, file='m3dv2.dat')
read(18,*) x // <---

do
  read(18,*) x
  tmp = sqrt(x**2 + 1)
  write(19, *) tmp
end do
```

The line added just reads the first line and then overwrites it with the seconde on the first iteration.

Comment: I think yours assumes the information on the first line of the file is of the same type as the second line.

Comment: @jonsca: yes, I do assume, unless other claimed.

Comment: No, first line is not a single number, but a combination of numbers and texts

Comment: So you'd probably be better off reading the top line into a char array of appropriate length, otherwise you'll get a runtime error, I believe (assuming from line 2 on down are `integers` or `double precision`, etc.)

Comment: yes (`string number string number`), but universal solution is welcome too.

Comment: @osgx: the universal solution is to read chars one by one in a loop intil you encounter '\0' char. There also can be a procedure which do this, sorta GetString() in C.

Comment: @suddnely_me there is no '\0' in Fortan